# SQL: Select within Select as subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I've got the following statement:

```
select 
    product_name as ShortestLength = (select top 1 product_name, len(fact_name) Value_Length 
                                      from table 
                                      order by Value_Length, fact_name ASC)
```

Which returns this output:

```
shortestlength
PS
```

I'd like to add this outcome to another select statement:

```
select
    'Product' as Column_Name,
    avg(case when product is null then 1.000 else 0 end) * 100 as PctMissing,
    count(product) as TotalCount,
    count(distinct product) as UniqueCount
from 
    table
```

so the result will be:

| column_name | pctmissing | totalcount | uniquecount | shortestlength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product | 5.100 | 181186 | 15 | PS |

What should I add to my initial select statement?

Comment: Your first query looks syntactically incorrect.  I think it should generate a syntax error.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Is `PS` here productname?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 'Product' as Column_Name,
        avg(case when t.product is null then 1.000 else 0 end)*100 as PctMissing,
        count(t.product) as TotalCount,
        count(distinct t.product) as UniqueCount,
        max(case when seqnum = 1 then product_name end) as shortest_length
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by len(fact_name), fact_name) as seqnum
      from table t 
     ) t
```

This assumes that the two `table` references are really the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use first query as subquery in place of a column in your select statement:

```
select
    'Product' as Column_Name,
    avg(case when product is null then 1.000 else 0 end)*100 as PctMissing,
    count(product) as TotalCount,
    count(distinct product) as UniqueCount,
(select top 1 product_name from table order by Value_Length, fact_name ASC) as ShortestLength 
from table
```